# How to store and gett variables in a widget?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

On the index page I load a custom made widget that I load with  .

This custom widget is a copy of **WP_Widget_Categories** with
The only changes i made is that instead of a dropdown or a list I now have a form with a few radioboxes (with category names) and a submit button.

When I check for example **"category-1"** and press the submit button I go to the **"mysiteurl/category/category-1"** page and I see all the posts of the category 1 page.

In the category.php page (just as in my index.php page). I have the same custom radiobutton widget implemented with:

```
  <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-category-checkbox-menu' ); ?>
```

The problem is when i get to the category page. The radiobox saying "category 1" should be checked because you are on that page. I need to have some sort of variable so i can know which category i am on now.

My first tries were:

1. Make a hidden field in my **form()** function of my widget and pass variables there.  But this seems messy.
2. I already gave my **radiobuttons name="cat"** and **value="$categoryid"** to get to the right category page. So i tried **$var_value = $_GET['cat'];**  This also did not work.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a custom widget for your sidebar ? 
You can manage "anything" you want from your widget PHP code, and display depending.